# DW Template for Multi Embedded Multi Component Link Field

Tags: templating

I'M trying to implement DW Template using the Useful TBB("Get Linked Component") found the following URL.
https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/generic-2011-tbbs.aspx

This TBB have the following function as one of all.

If Multi(each) Embedded field have component link field (also multiple value field), it pushs some Component arrays (which is consist of component link field values) to the package as the key of "[embedded field name][Index].[Component link field name] (ie: "embeddable_items1.product_item" "embeddable_items2.product_item" "embeddable_items3.product_item")

The problem is when you implement repeat structure in the DW Template, 
how can I get the TemplateRepeatIndex in the repeat condition?

I tried the following code, but an error has occured.

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Embeddable_Faq_List_Items${TemplateRepeatIndex}.Faq_Item" -->
       [some code here]
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Could you give me any idea for this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What error are you exactly getting, could you edit the question and update it with the specific error message and details?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to use the `TemplateRepeatIndex` inside a repeating or conditional statement as you are trying to do.

In my opinion you are pushing the boundaries of what the Tridion Dreamweaver templating language is capable of handling elegantly in terms of nested looping and embedded fields. You have several options:

1. Rework your content model to avoid using multivalue embedded multivalue component link fields (perhaps by using a component link instead of embedded schema) - Whether this makes sense or not should be evaluated from an Editorial point of view, rather than being driven by technical necessity however
2. Use a more flexible templating language, like [Razor](https://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/), or [XSLT](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/xsltmediator.aspx)
3. Abstract the generation of HTML for your linked faq components into a separate (embedded) Component Template, and call this from within a double loop:

### Sample

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Embeddable_Faq_List_Items" -->
  <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Field.Faq_Item" -->
    @@RenderComponentPresentation(Field,FaqItemEmbeddedComponentTemplateUri)@@
  <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Note that you will need to push into the package a variable called `FaqItemEmbeddedComponentTemplateUri` which contains the Uri of the embedded CT.

Comment: Good one on the mention of #3, which I also explain here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/729/28

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are looking for this:-

**[IteratingOverMultivalueEmbeddedFields](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/IteratingOverMultivalueEmbeddedFields)**, this is the best example wrote on tridion-pratice page.

### Sample:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Component.Fields" -->
    @@Field.Name@@
    <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Field.Values" -->
        <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Field.ContentType = 'text/plain'" -->
            @@RenderComponentField(FieldPath, TemplateRepeatIndex)@@
        <!-- TemplateEndIf -->
        <!-- TemplateBeginIf cond="Field.ContentType = 'tridion/field'" -->       
            <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Field.Fields" -->         
                @@Field.Name@@         
                <!-- TemplateBeginRepeat name="Field.Values" -->          
                    @@RenderComponentField(FieldPath, TemplateRepeatIndex)@@                
                <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->       
            <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->     
        <!-- TemplateEndIf -->   
    <!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
<!-- TemplateEndRepeat -->
```

Comment: That's a good generic example, but [Frank explained it doesn't address repeating over specific fields](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10322575/395495), or in this case how to reference `@@TemplateRepeatIndex@@` with DGX.