# Making image field editable via Experience Manager

Tags: experience-manager

Is it possible to change the image field via experience Manager?
plz provide me with the code as well as I tried to put tcdl tag code but could not get the desired behavior.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried and explain why it falls short.

Comment: Good question, but the this repeats http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/818/46 and without more info should probably be closed. The expected behavior depends on the setup--"image field" with `tcdl` suggests you should expect the library nav without additional instructions on the page (as opposed to `RenderComponentField()`..