# Inline editing for image in XPM

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, siteedit, 2013-sp1

I am trying to edit an image field of a component through XPM but not able to get the desired options. Below is the screen shot

[image]

I have taken all the steps described in this question : "[How to change image using Experience Manager?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/818/how-to-change-image-using-experience-manager)"

The markup is getting created properly:

```
 <div><span><!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:55-211",
 "ComponentModified" : "2014-07-24T07:41:48", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:55-727-32", 
"ComponentTemplateModified" : "2014-07-24T07:49:17", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false } -
->

 <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:largeimage[1]"} 
-->
<img src="/Images/products-wipers.png"  alt="hello"/>
</span></div>

   <!-- Page Settings: {"PageID":"tcm:55-720-64","PageModified":"2014-07-24T07:49:45",
"PageTemplateID":"tcm:55-178-128","PageTemplateModified":"2014-07-23T09:06:42"} -->

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" defer="defer" 
src="http://tridiondev/WebUI/Editors/SiteEdit/Views/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js" 
id="tridion.siteedit"></script></body>
```

Is there any specific JAR file required for Image editing in XPM which could be missing?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not 100% on this but you may need another div/span around the image and its XPM field markup.

Answer (score 2):

So looking at your screenshot I'm assuming the problem you are referring to is that the border  in XPM does not match the size of your image right? *(in that case, it would be beneficial that you update your question and make the actual problem a bit more clear)*

The border as shown in XPM is generated based on the XPM markup and the HTML elements around that. In your case you want a border around an `img` element (which is an inline block level element), and for that you have the `<!-- Start Component Field: {...} -->` markup placed above it and wrapped in a `span` element.

Now the `span` element is in HTML a inline element, and this is what is used by XPM to draw the border, so it will pick up the width of your image, but unfortunately, it won't pick up the height of the image. If you would change that `span` into a `div` (which is a block level element), you will notice that the border will be nicely around your image.

Now the next (possible) issue is that you have both the `<!-- Start Component Presentation: {...} -->` and the `<!-- Start Component Field: {...} -->` markup wrapped in the same HTML element (in your case the `span`). This means that both the Component Presentation border and the Component Field border (the border around the image), will have the exact same size. So when you hover over the image, you will never see the Component Presentation border, or at the least it will be difficult to reach. Ideally you should adjust the HTML to work better with XPM, and you could consider something like:

```html
<div><!-- Start Component Presentation: {"ComponentID" : "tcm:55-211", "ComponentModified" : "2014-07-24T07:41:48", "ComponentTemplateID" : "tcm:55-727-32", "ComponentTemplateModified" : "2014-07-24T07:49:17", "IsRepositoryPublished" : false } -->
    <div><!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:largeimage[1]"} -->
        <img src="/Images/products-wipers.png"  alt="hello"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems a minor change, but it will have a huge effect on the usability. Other options could be to give the `span` (or whatever other HTML element you are using to wrap the XPM markup in) a different display properly (like `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`), see also http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Thanks Brat, but i'm still not able to edit the image.

I have applied the div tags as described by you. After doing so, I am able to get the proper border around the image and on clicking the image it opens the "Edit multimedia link" panel in XPM. But as soon as I click on apply after selecting a multimedia component, it throws this error: 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IdentifiableObjectData. There are multiple root elements. Line 18, position 267.'

Comment: Also, i believe that these divs and spans are auto generated on page, I have just provided the inline editing markup on dwt.. something like this: '
  <!-- Start Component Field: {"XPath" : "tcm:Content/custom:Content/custom:largeimage[1]"} -->
<img src="@@Component.Fields.largeimage@@" tridion:type="Multimedia" alt="hello"/>"'

Is there anything that is incorrect in this markup.. Please suggest.. Thanks

Comment: @Saurabh if your problem is not selecting the image but changing it, and you get an error, then EDIT your question and add the error in there, how do you expect to get answer to the issue when you don't specify the information in your question? Nobody has a crystal ball here you know, oh and please put on your reading glasses since my name is not Brat.

Comment: @Saurabh with regards to the `div` and `span` being auto generated, while you have put on your reading glasses, I think it is about time to start reading the documentation and see what options you can specify in the Inline Editing TBBs, you have full control over what HTML you want it to create for you there.

Comment: Ok.. thanks "Bart".. and sorry for the name.. :)